# sql, # 1067 - Wrong default value for 'published'

Tags: mysql, sql

i try to add attribute UNSIGNED to my column, i use this

```
ALTER TABLE `m_material` CHANGE `id` `id` INT(7) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

but i have error

```
# 1067 - Wrong default value for 'published'
```

what is this error and how to get rid of it

[image]

Comment: The error is for the `published timestamp` column. Nothing to do with what you changed.

Comment: My guess is that your server mode is not allowing zero timestamp default values.  See the duplicate link for how to fix your problem.